# Need to check if table exists in SQlite with JS

Tags: javascript, sqlite, exists

I haven't been able to find whether a table exists in my DB. I open/create it with JS like this:

```
DEMODB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
```

and then:

```
DEMODB.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' and name='MyTable'", [],
      function(tx, result) {
         //console.log(result.rows);
         cont = result.rows.length;
      },
      function(tx, error){
         // error occured
      }
   );
});
```

*cont* always has 1 (if the function is executed). I also tried this:

```
pragma table_info('abreviations'
```

but I get error "missing authorization".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You get one record back because even if the table is missing, the *count* of such tables exists (but is zero).

Check whether the *value* you get back is zero or one.

Alternatively, just try to read from the table and handle the error.